# Prebid bid adapter get no response from DFP

Tags: prebid.js, prebid

I'm pretty new to the world of Header Bidding and some mechanics are not very clear to me, anyway I have to write my own bid adapter (only `native`).

I have defined the functions `isBidRequestValid()` `buildRequests()` `interpretResponse()` `onBidWon()`. For testing purpouse I'm using `integrationExamples/gpt/native_example.html`  with `appnexusAdapter` and `mycustomAdapter`.

I'm able to create the bid requests for my bidder’s server and parsing the bid responses. But I'm stuck on this, when my bids are higher than appnexus bids, I get no response from DFP and the `onBidWon()` event is not fired. While if the appenxus bids are higher than mine, I get a valid response from DFP, the `appnexus onBidWon()` event is fired and the adUnits are populated with the appnexus creatives.

AppNexus responds with two creatives ($0.5 cpm and $10.00 cpm), my server also responds with two creatives with random cpm (1-100).

That's an example of bid returned by `interpretResponse`:

```
{
   adUnitCode: "/19968336/prebid_native_example_1",
   cpm: 15,
   creativeId: "5ce6aa65bdf6bf2d36654a2d",
   currency: "EUR",
   height: 1,
   mediaType: "native",
   native: {
      title: "Other great advices to try",
      sponsoredBy: "Other Great Company",
      clickUrl: "https://affiliate.company.com/click/cn9s9c627i",
      image: {
         height: 1,
         url: "https://cdn.mysite.com/5f9aaf8b0afcd63d2c35d180.jpg",
         width: 1,
      }
   },
   netRevenue: true
   requestId: "2f30d517a4c847"
   ttl: 300,
   width: 1,
}
```

From the console log I can see the following info:

```
INFO: Invoking pbjs.onEvent Arguments
INFO: Invoking pbjs.addAdUnits 
MESSAGE: Emitting event for: addAdUnits
MESSAGE: Emitting event for: requestBids
INFO: Invoking pbjs.requestBids
MESSAGE: Emitting event for: beforeRequestBids
INFO: Bids Requested for Auction with id: f90900e7-b0da-41a1-a834-e5ca4f234891
MESSAGE: Emitting event for: auctionInit
MESSAGE: CALLING BIDDER ======= appnexus
MESSAGE: Emitting event for: bidRequested
MESSAGE: CALLING BIDDER ======= custom
MESSAGE: Emitting event for: bidRequested
MESSAGE: Emitting event for: bidAdjustment
INFO: suppressing empty key 'hb_deal' from adserver targeting
MESSAGE: Emitting event for: bidResponse
MESSAGE: Emitting event for: bidAdjustment
INFO: suppressing empty key 'hb_deal' from adserver targeting
MESSAGE: Emitting event for: bidResponse
MESSAGE: Emitting event for: bidderDone
MESSAGE: Emitting event for: bidAdjustment
INFO: suppressing empty key 'hb_deal' from adserver targeting
MESSAGE: Emitting event for: bidResponse
INFO: Bids Received for Auction with id: f90900e7-b0da-41a1-a834-e5ca4f234891
MESSAGE: Emitting event for: auctionEnd
INFO: Invoking pbjs.setTargetingForGPTAsync
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_native_image value: https://cdn.mysite.com/5f9aaf8b0afcd63d2c35d180.jpg
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_native_linkurl value: https://affiliate.company.com/click/39e6e1dwog
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_native_brand value: Great Company
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_native_title value: Try our best advises
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_format value: native
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_source value: client
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_size value: 1x1
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_pb value: 32.00
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_adid value: 608908d3f29299
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_bidder value: custom
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_native_linkurl_cu value: https://affiliate.company.com/click/39e6e1dwog
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_native_image_cust value: https://cdn.mysite.com/5f9aaf8b0afcd63d2c35d180.jpg
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_native_brand_cust value: Great Company
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_native_title_cust value: Try our best advices
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_format_custom value: native
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_source_custom value: client
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_size_custom value: 1x1
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_pb_custom value: 32.00
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_adid_custom value: 608908d3f29299
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_bidder_custom value: custom
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_native_linkurl_ap value: http://prebid.org/dev-docs/show-native-ads.html
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_native_image_appn value: https://vcdn.adnxs.com/p/creative-image/94/22/cd/0f/9422cd0f-f400-45d3-80f5-2b92629d9257.jpg
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_native_brand_appn value: Prebid.org
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_native_title_appn value: This is a Prebid Native Creative
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_format_appnexus value: native
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_source_appnexus value: client
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_size_appnexus value: 0x0
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_pb_appnexus value: 10.00
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_adid_appnexus value: 8fedccc6ce9763
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-1 key: hb_bidder_appnexus value: appnexus
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-2 key: hb_native_image value: https://cdn.mysite.com/5f9aaf8b0afcd63d2c35d180.jpg
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-2 key: hb_native_linkurl value: https://affiliate.company.com/click/cn9s9c627i
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-2 key: hb_native_brand value: Other Great Company
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-2 key: hb_native_title value: Other great advices to try
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-2 key: hb_format value: native
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-2 key: hb_source value: client
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-2 key: hb_size value: 1x1
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-2 key: hb_pb value: 15.00
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-2 key: hb_adid value: 7c0389e2b81406
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-2 key: hb_bidder value: custom
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-2 key: hb_native_linkurl_cu value: https://affiliate.company.com/click/cn9s9c627i
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-2 key: hb_native_image_cust value: https://cdn.mysite.com/5f9aaf8b0afcd63d2c35d180.jpg
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-2 key: hb_native_brand_cust value: Other Great Company
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-2 key: hb_native_title_cust value: Other great advices to try
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-2 key: hb_format_custom value: native
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-2 key: hb_source_custom value: client
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-2 key: hb_size_custom value: 1x1
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-2 key: hb_pb_custom value: 15.00
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-2 key: hb_adid_custom value: 7c0389e2b81406
MESSAGE: Attempting to set key value for slot: div-2 key: hb_bidder_custom value: custom
MESSAGE: Emitting event for: setTargeting
MESSAGE: Emitting event for: bidderDone
```

I suppose that I'm missing some configuration, because I get no error at all.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello @fasenderos i'm facing with the same issue, probably you have find the solution ?

Comment: you can check your DFP line item setup. mostly issue lies there it seems. `onBidWon()` is called only after the creative renders on page